# How to count frequencies from a nested list that is a column in a df?

Tags: python, pandas, list, nested-lists

I want to count the occurrences of an item in nested lists. The current structure of the Pandas df; each record was grouped by a match_id and possession_id and then passed values second, action_name, player_name to a list called action_seq.

I can count the total of events within each possession no problem but I now want to be able to count the number of times for e.g. Player A has been involved in events? What events have they occurred more frequent in?

```
#sample df
pass_goal = pd.DataFrame({'match_id': [1107073,1107073,1107073,1409630,1409630], 
'possession_number': [2,2,2,40,40], 'second': [10,15,20,250,260], 
'action_name': ['pass', 'pass', 'goal','pass','goal'], 
'player_name': ['a','b','c','a','b']})

#grouping by match and possession then adding a list
posses = pass_goal.groupby(['match_id','possession_number'])[['second', 'action_name','player_name']].apply(lambda action: action.values.tolist()).reset_index(name='action_seq')
```

Preferred Output

```
Player A B C
Pass   2 1 0
Goal   0 1 1
```

Comment: Please provide us with a sample dataframe that we don't have to type in by hand and the desired result for that dataframe.

Comment: @timgeb I have updated with sample dataframe and desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
(pass_goal[["action_name","player_name"]]
 .pivot_table(columns="player_name", index="action_name", aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
 .rename_axis(index="", columns="player"))

player       a  b  c

goal         0  1  1
pass         2  1  0
```

Comment: your output does **not** match the desired output ... action `goal` occurs twice for player `a` for example

Comment: Edited. A typo.